# Is it possible on modern day browsers to restrict user activity like open new browser window or open new tab via use of shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, ejs

I know it is generally frowned upon to restrict general browser functionality, but I do have a valid usecase.

Im working on project about an online testing platform.
Whenever a user starts their test, it enters a full screen mode and the test ends when they exit full screen mode.

So i was wondering if it is possible to restrict functions like ctrl + t (new tab) or ctrl + n (new window) while on the test window (full screen)?

i've already implemented that if the user opens a new tab or window using the shortcuts their test ends. But i was wondering if there is a better way to do this or disable those shortcuts completely.

So far i have tried things like

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.key === 't' || e.key === 'n')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I suspect it doesn't work on modern browsers, is there any way around it? can I bypass it?